# Give numbering in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi I wanted to give numbering to the strings found in range of cells, can some one help in solving this

For example in a Excel sheet..Following data is present

Col1

---

A

B

C

D

B

E

A

F

I want the following result

Col1    Col2

---

A  1

B  1

C  1

D    1

B    2

E    1

A    2

F    1

A    3

B     3

Comment: Check out the COUNTIF formula.

Comment: Contif gives total count, don't give sequence numbering.please check above example once

Comment: Seems you're the expert, so you won't be needing my help.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help...Try if possible

Comment: I've given you a pointer. At least check it out before dismissing it. This site prefers people to make an effort before asking questions.

Comment: You could have at least tried using @SJR solution

Comment: Hey I tried man, I do respect SJR solution, but I didn't get any idea to solve. Please let me know if you find any way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, let me know if this is what you required.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
i = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

For k = 1 To i

If Cells(k, 2).Value = "" Then

a = Cells(k, 1).Value
For j = k + 1 To i

b = Cells(j, 1).Value
If a = b Then
temp = temp + 1
Cells(j, 2).Value = temp
End If
Next

temp = 0
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I thought there could be some function which will give the expected results.

Comment: Ah..as per my knowledge the requirement what you have could be fulfilled by a macro only, not by any formula.

Comment: This is ridiculous. the solution by @SJR was a much easier solution than writing code. Did you even try it out....